# How to make Slider move automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

Please help me make my slider move automatically. Everything works well, the only thing missing is to make the slider move automatically. The code below is a template of my work. Please help make the photos move automatically for around 3 to 5 seconds per photo. I have tried different ways to make the slider automatically move but it makes the photos lose its responsiveness and position.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const navigation = document.querySelector(".navigation");

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle("active");
  navigation.classList.toggle("active");
});

const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-btn");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".img-slide");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

var sliderNav = function(manual) {
  btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.classList.remove("active");
  });

  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove("active");
  });

  contents.forEach((content) => {
    content.classList.remove("active");
  });

  btns[manual].classList.add("active");
  slides[manual].classList.add("active");
  contents[manual].classList.add("active");
}

btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sliderNav(i)
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 200px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

header .brand {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

header .brand:hover {
  color: #14723d
}

header .navigation {
  position: relative;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  background: #14723d;
  font-weight: 900;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 200px;
}

.home {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #14723d
}

.home:before {
  z-index: 777;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(251, 3, 3, 0.034);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.home .content {
  z-index: 888;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: none;
}


/*
.home .content .wrapper
{
    
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 30%;
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
      
}

*/

.home .content.active {
  display: block;
}

.home .content h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  line-height: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-shadow: 7px 7px/*#14723d */
  black;
}

.home .content span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.home .content span1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
}

.home .content p {
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.home .content a {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #14723d;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.home .content a:hover {
  background: #14723d;
  color: #fff;
}

.home .media-icons {
  z-index: 888;
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.home .media-icons a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.home .media-icons a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.home .media-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #14723d
}

.home img {
  z-index: 000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-navigation {
  z-index: 888;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(135px);
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn.active {
  background: #14723d;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.img-slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(0% at 0 50%);
}

.img-slide.active {
  clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
  transition: 2s ease;
  transition-property: clip-path;
}

@media (max-width: 1040px) {
  header {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 100px 20px;
  }
  .home .media-icons {
    right: 15px;
  }
  header .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  header .navigation.active {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  }
  header .navigation .navigation-items a {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
    background: #222;
    height: 5px;
  }
  header .navigation .navigation-items {
    background: #fff;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 20%);
  }
  .menu-btn {
    background: url(menu.png)no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .menu-btn.active {
    z-index: 999;
    background: url(close.png)no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px;
    background-position: center;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
  .home .content h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 60px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
  .home .content a {
    background: white;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    color: #14723d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
<header>
  <a href="#" class="brand">SAMPLE</a>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="navigation-items">
        <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
        <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
        <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
        <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
        <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="home">

  <img decoding="async" class="img-slide active" src="1.jpg"></img>
  <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="2.jpg"></img>
  <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="3.jpg"></img>
  <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="4.jpg"></img>
  <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="5.jpg"></img>
  <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="6.jpg"></img>
  <div class="content active">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1>
      <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
      <!--   <p>text</p> -->
      <a href="#">Visit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1> <span>SAMPLE</span> <br><br>
    <!--  <p>text</p> -->
    <a href="#">Visit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>try<br> </h1> <span>SAMPLE</span> <br><br>
    <!--  <p>try</p> -->
    <a href="#">Visit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>help<br> </h1>
    <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
    <!--  <p>help</p> -->
    <a href="#">Visit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1>
    <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
    <!--  <p>sample</p> -->
    <a href="#">Visit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1>
    <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
    <!--  <p>sample</p> -->
    <a href="#">Visit </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-icons">
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-navigation">
    <div class="nav-btn active"></div>
    <div class="nav-btn"></div>
    <div class="nav-btn"></div>
    <div class="nav-btn"></div>
    <div class="nav-btn"></div>
    <div class="nav-btn"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="main.js" defer data-deferred="1"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const navigation = document.querySelector(".navigation");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-btn");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".img-slide");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
let currentIndex = 0;
let intervalId;

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("active");
    navigation.classList.toggle("active");
});

const sliderNav = function(manual) {
    btns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove("active");
    });

    slides.forEach((slide) => {
        slide.classList.remove("active");
    });

    contents.forEach((content) => {
        content.classList.remove("active");
    });

    btns[manual].classList.add("active");
    slides[manual].classList.add("active");
    contents[manual].classList.add("active");
}

btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        sliderNav(i);
        currentIndex = i;
        clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop auto-slide when user manually clicks on a navigation button
        startAutoSlide(); // Restart auto-slide after manual interaction
    });
});

// Function to auto slide
const autoSlide = () => {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length;
    sliderNav(currentIndex);
}

// Start auto slide
const startAutoSlide = () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(autoSlide, 1000);
    // Change slide every 3 seconds
}

startAutoSlide(); // Start auto-slide when the page loads
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}



header{
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 200px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

header .brand{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0;
    
}

header .brand:hover{
    color: #14723d
}

header .navigation{
    position: relative;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a{
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
   
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a:hover:before{
    width: 100%;
    background: #14723d;
    font-weight: 900;
}

section{
    padding: 100px 200px;
}

.home {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #14723d
}

.home:before{
    z-index: 777;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(251, 3, 3, 0.034);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.home .content{
    z-index: 888;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
}


/*
.home .content .wrapper
{
    
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 30%;
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
      
}

*/
.home .content.active{
    display: block;
}

.home .content h1{
    font-size: 6em;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-shadow: 7px 7px /*#14723d */ black;
}


.home .content span{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    
}
.home .content span1{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0;
    
}

.home .content p{
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.home .content a{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    color: #14723d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

    
  
}

.home .content a:hover{
    background: #14723d;
    color: #fff;
}

.home .media-icons{
    z-index: 888;
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.home .media-icons a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.home .media-icons a:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.home .media-icons a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    color: #14723d
}

.home img{
    z-index: 000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-navigation{
    z-index: 888;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateY(135px);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn.active{
    background: #14723d;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.img-slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    clip-path: circle(0% at 0 50%);
}

.img-slide.active{
    clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
    transition: 2s ease;
    transition-property: clip-path;
}

@media (max-width: 1040px){
    header{
        padding: 12px 20px;
    }
    section{
        padding: 100px 20px;
    }
    .home .media-icons{
        right: 15px;
    }
    header .navigation{
        display: none;
    }
    header .navigation.active{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
    }

    header .navigation .navigation-items a{
        color: #222;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    header .navigation .navigation-items a:before{
        background: #222;
        height: 5px;
    }
    header .navigation .navigation-items{
        background: #fff;
        width: 600px;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 40px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 20%);
    }
    .menu-btn{
        background: url(menu.png)no-repeat;
        background-size: 30px;
        background-position: center;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
    .menu-btn.active{
        z-index: 999;
        background: url(close.png)no-repeat;
        background-size: 25px;
        background-position: center;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 560px){
    .home .content h1{
        font-size: 2em;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 560px){
    .home .content a{
        background: white;
        padding: 7px 15px;
        color: #14723d;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LANDING PAGE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="#" class="brand">SAMPLE</a>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation-items">
                    <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
                    <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
                    <a href="#">SAMPLE</a> 
                    <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
                    <a href="#">SAMPLE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="home">

        <img decoding="async" class="img-slide active" src="1.jpg" ></img>
        <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="2.jpg" ></img>
        <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="3.jpg" ></img>
        <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="4.jpg" ></img>
        <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="5.jpg" ></img>
        <img decoding="async" class="img-slide" src="6.jpg" ></img>
        <div class="content active">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1> <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
        <!--   <p>text</p> --> 
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1> <span>SAMPLE</span> <br><br>
        <!--  <p>text</p> --> 
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>try<br> </h1> <span>SAMPLE</span> <br><br>
        <!--  <p>try</p> --> 
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>help<br> </h1> <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
        <!--  <p>help</p> --> 
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>SAMPLE<br> </h1>  <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
        <!--  <p>sample</p> -->
          <a href="#">Visit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h1>SAMPLE<br>  </h1>  <span1>SAMPLE TEXT</span1> <br><br>
        <!--  <p>sample</p> -->
          <a href="#">Visit </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-navigation">
            <div class="nav-btn active"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>

        </div>
    </section> 
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YOU can change duration as you want 
one is other option is you can use swiper.js lib where many options for crousel